# RxJava recebendo os dados

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Como fazer pra separar esse array em 3 arrays, tipo um pra gradesList, um pra faultList e outro pra classList. To usando RxJava.

> [GradeList(gradesList=4.5, faultList=5, classList=math),
>   GradeList(gradesList=9.5, faultList=10, classList=math)]

Comment: Sua pergunta tá absurdamente confusa. Por favor, tente [edit] e explicar com calma o que deseja.

Comment: Acho q nem editando deixa de ser confusa rsrs mds. É que tipo to usando RxJava, e ae quero reproduzir 3 arrays na view. Só que, em vez de me dar acesso a cada tipo de array, q vem do JSON, ele me dá só um único array com td junto. 

**Ex:** `[GradeList(gradesList=4.5, faultList=5, classList=math), GradeList(gradesList=9.5, faultList=10, classList=math)]`

E eu queria tipo um array pra cada, um pra gradesList, um pra faultList e um pra classList.

Comment: O que tem é um array de um tipo com esses 3 atributos ou uma string com esse conteúdo?

Comment: um array de um tipo com esses três atributos diferentes. Eu recebo um JSON que tem esses dados.